# no estoy logrando poder cambiar los fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.facebook.accountkit.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.accountkit.Account;
import com.facebook.accountkit.AccountKit;
import com.facebook.accountkit.AccountKitCallback;
import com.facebook.accountkit.AccountKitError;
import com.facebook.accountkit.PhoneNumber;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setFragment(0);

        //Verificacion de inicio de sesion
        AccountKit.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        AccessToken accessToken = AccountKit.getCurrentAccessToken();

        if (accessToken == null) {
            IrLogin();
        }

        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.inicio:
                        setFragment(0);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.buscar:
                        setFragment(1);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.perfil:
                        setFragment(2);
                        return true;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setFragment(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Fragment fragment1 = new frInicio();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1).commit();
                break;

            case 1:
                Fragment fragment2 = new frBuscarPerfiles();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2).commit();

                break;
            case 2:
                Fragment fragment3 = new frPerfil();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment3).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Activity Main

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/barainf" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/barainf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                design:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

menu_navigation

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:title="@string/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:id="@+id/inicio">
    </item>
    <item
        android:title="buscar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_explore"
        android:id="@+id/buscar">
    </item>
    <item
        android:title="pefil"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
        android:id="@+id/perfil">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Algún mensaje en el LogCat? simplemente no lo muestra?

Comment: al ejecutar la aplicación, me muestra el primer fragmento, y cuando pulso uno de los items se selecciona pero no cambia el fragmento

Comment: Ok esto da más idea de cual es el problema, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Usa una instancia de `Fragment` (en este caso `fragment`) del tipo obtenido en el `switch` y realiza la transacción:

```
public void setFragment(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new frInicio();
            break;

        case 1:
            fragment = new frBuscarPerfiles();
            break;

        case 2:
            fragment = new frPerfil();
            break;                
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();                  
    }
}
```

De esta forma la instancia de `fragment` va a ser reemplazada siempre.

---

**Actualización:** al revisar tu `layout`, donde intentas agregar el `Fragment`, `fragment_container` es un `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/barainf" />
```

debe ser un `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

o un `Fragment` si deseas agregar directamente el `Fragment`.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:name="<PÄQUETE>Fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: sigue haciendo lo mismo, intenté cambiar en el onCreate "setFragment(0);" por "setFragment(2);" y sigue sucediendo lo mismo, asi que pegue el código del menú, capaz es algo de eso o nose.

Comment: android:id="@+id/fragment_container" debe ser FrameLayout

Comment: intente eso y sigue pasando, se volvió algo turbio por que intente en sacar del código el frInicio y aun así se sigue inflando ese mismo fragmento

Answer (score 0):

Si no has solucionado aún tu problema, tengo un proyecto con solo un `navigation drawer` que cambia los fragmentos.

Puedes copiar la [estructura del proyecto](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0hwgcIwH6xceWh6dFJUN3NGU0k/view).